# How to capture multiple HTTP headers with the same name (ex.: set-cookie) in HAProxy?

Tags: proxy, http, cookies, http-proxy, haproxy

I want to capture and log all the Set-Cookie headers in HTTP responses. The problem is that I only get the last Set-Cookie in my log lines. I am using haproxy 1.7 in docker (FROM haproxy:1.7). My config file's frontend section looks like this:

```
frontend http-in
    capture request header cookie len 100
    capture response header set-cookie len 1000
    log-format "%ci:%cp [%t] %hr %hs %{+Q}r"
```

A sample HTTP response header section looks like this:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
server: Server
date: Thu, 04 Jul 2019 08:36:39 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment
content-language: de-DE
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
cache-control: no-cache
pragma: no-cache
expires: -1
content-encoding: gzip
x-xss-protection: 1;
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
set-cookie: session-id=257-4934332-2510024; Domain=.amazon.de; Expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT; Path=/
set-cookie: session-id-time=2082787201l; Domain=.amazon.de; Expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT; Path=/
set-cookie: i18n-prefs=EUR; Domain=.amazon.de; Expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT; Path=/
x-amz-rid: XAVKCTHFYAMGP6C4GZ66
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
via: 1.1 f0a97a8c56cd2bb79a1739863489ed4c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: FRA6-C1
x-amz-cf-id: PZySU6Kl1g5gKK7Cn6HOGtowfauRyA-R3U_1FXHDlkO2ZyfnnHpuBg==
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Only the last from the three set-cookie headers appears in the logs.
The names of the cookies can be completely different (no prefix) so I cannot use `capture cookie`.

Is there a way to capture and log all the Set-Cookie headers in haproxy?